# Error message "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from type ‘char *’"

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, char

The compiler gives me an error, "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from type ‘char *’" when I try to execute the following line:

```
records[i].address = records[i+1].address;
```

`records` is an array of struct rec with the following definition:

```
struct rec{
    char address[100];
}
```

Why is it giving me this error? The left and right side is the same type.

Comment: Unless you're interfacing to COBOL or FORTRAN code, just use `std::string`.

Comment: As you tagged C++ then I recommend you use `std::string` which will probably just work with the syntax you expect.

Comment: @Axalo: C and C++ are different languages. The OP has unwisely tagged this question with both languages. One can reasonably assume that it's the "C" tag that's superfluous and incorrect, in which case the information in your suggested duplicate is wrong for this question.

Comment: @mspatel: Please pick either C or C++, according to how you compile your code.  Until you do, answers which are correct in one language and incorrect in the other are just going to lead to flamewars.

Answer (score 2):

`char[100]` is not the same type as `char *`.  One is an array of 100 character variables, the other is a variable that contains the address of a character variable.

You can "assign" a `char[100]` to a `char *` only because a "bare" array evaluates to the address of its first element - an address can't hold anything - it's not a variable, it's **where** a variable is.

Thus,

```
char array[ 100 ];
char *ptr = array;
```

works, while

```
char array[ 100 ];
char *ptr;
array=ptr;
```

does not.  The first case is saying `ptr` now points to the first element of `array`.  The second is "the address of `array` should be assigned the value of `ptr`, which is literally nonsense.

Comment: This answer is of the sort "I can think of a silly explanation, therefore the thing must be silly". But hey, that's silly. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Who was it who said "If you can't explain something in words that can be understood by a third grader, you don't understand it."? It's your turn to start explaining - using short words.

Comment: I believe you're referring to Albert Einstein's comment about explaining to six year olds. At that age I was in first grade. Anyway, in C++ array expressions are lvalues, e.g. can be passed by reference to functions (there's no such thing in C).  And as Neil Kirk commented elsewhere here, it's easy to think of reasonable semantics for an assignment to array. E.g., in `a = p` one reasonable interpretation could be that `p` points to the first item of an array of at least the size of `a`. The whole thing with arrays is, however, a mess. In C++ the implicit conversions break things.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to arrays, and if you think about it, that doesn't make sense, to copy the **contents** of the array, assuming it's a string you need `strcpy()`, for example

```
strcpy(records[i].address, records[i+1].address);
```

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense to assign arrays?

Comment: Which element would you assign to which? It does make sense to have a pointer to an array of course, but that is not the same.

Comment: The same as `struct Array { char temp[100]; } a, b; a = b;` would do (simple point of example)

Comment: @NeilKirk: technically, a bare array reference (one without []s), is not an "lvalue".  It's not something that can be assigned to as it merely evaluates to the address of the first element of the array.  You can't assign "4" to where the array is - the array is where it is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am not talking about the rules of C, but the general concept of assigning arrays. I can think of reasonable semantics for assigning arrays, therefore the simple fact "it doesn't make sense" shouldn't be used as an argument against it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: re " is not an "lvalue", that's incorrect for C++.

Comment: I don't like how programmers who learn to assign arrays in programming languages like c++ using any of the `stl` classes for example, think. If you learn to think like a c programmer you will write better programs, it's of course my opinion and is most likely wrong for most people, but it's correct for me.

Comment: @NeilKirk - It literally does not make sense to say "assign 891234 to the address of the first element of this array."  You can put mail in a mailbox.  That mailbox has an address.  You can not put mail into the address of the mailbox - the address is not a physical thing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I did not say it makes sense to assign any old type to an array.

Comment: @iharob How does liking `str1 = str2;` instead of `strcpy(str1, str2);` negatively affect the way I think?

Comment: Yes, it shadows the understanding of how `str1` is represented in memory, there is no problem if you know that, but programmers who learn that first, will have problems whenever they need to use a programming language that does not hide such a fundamental fact, please do not post a response since this is not the place for the discussion, I will not answer any question related to this again.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have mentioned the difference between `char a[]` and `char * a`. I want to make it more cleanly.

In `char a[]`, `a` just denotes an array address, not a variable, which means it cannot be assigned. Actually, **`a` will be replaced by the final address when it was compiled to executable**.  you can't assign a value to a value.

For example,

foo.c:

```
char *myvar = "hello";

int 
main() {
    return myvar[0];
}
```

run

```
gcc foo.c -o foo ; objdump -S foo
```

You'll get:

```
mov    0x2003ef(%rip),%rax      # put value of `myvar` into %rax

movzbl (%rax),%eax              # put *myvar into %eax
```

After you replaced `char *myvar = "hello"` with `char myvar[] = "hello"`, you'll just get one line:

```
movzbl 0x2003e7(%rip),%eax    # put address of array `myvar` into %eax
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I will assume that this question is about C++, since it's tagged C++. The C tag is problematic because C is a different language with *similar* but not exactly identical rules. And for programming the devil is in the details.

Now, given

```
int const n = ....;

struct rec{
    char address[100];
};

rec records[n];
```

you can't do

```
records[i].address=records[i+1].address;
```

because a raw array isn't assignable. There's no good reason for it, AFAIK. But probably a main driver was that in early C one focused on being able to define functions that could work with any length array, and [Brian Kernighan ridiculed Pascal](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html) (with array assignment) for its inability to express such generally useful functions.

On the other hand, you can do

```
records[i]=records[i+1];
```

because class instances are assignable by default.

As a kind of opposite case (or similar case, depending on what features one focuses on), when a function returns a class instance by value, then its assignment operator lets you assign to the whole instance (because member functions can be called on rvalues), but the rvalue-ness of the function call expression prevents you from assigning to a basic type member. Both these rules, the one about array member and the one about rvalue, can seem pretty arbitrary to a beginner. And they are. ;-)

Anyway, what you should do is use a `std::string` instead of a raw array of `char`, like this:

```
struct rec{
    std::string address;
};
```

Then you can assign just the `address` member, or the whole `struct`, as you wish.